# Meaning of "transform the real line"

Tags: functions

The interval in which the function 
$$f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x^2-3x+3}$$ transforms the real line is

I just want to know what is the meaning of transform the real line ?

Answer (score 2):

They are asking you to find $f(\Bbb R)$, i.e. $\text{Im} f$